# install CVXpy: compile failed with error code 1

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, cvxpy

I am trying to install CVXpy on Ubuntu 14.04, with python 2.7.6, pip 1.5.4. I tried the way proposed here:
http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/install/index.html

It runs smoothly until: nosetests cvxpy
where I get the error:

ImportError: No module named canonInterface

So I tried to install the package CVXcanon but the command
pip install CVXcanon
gives the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='/tmp/pip_build_baptiste/CVXcanon/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /tmp/pip-_ehIzX-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile 
failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_baptiste/CVXcanon
```

Would you have an advice on how to get this issue settled? Thank you.

Comment: error code 1 is a permissions error. Try running as sudo?